# RoR: how can I let people see the users link without being signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make it so that people who dont have account/are not signed in can see the list of users and all the users posts..

in my users_controller.rb I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, 
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

I am guessing that the before_filter :signed_in_user is what makes it so only signed in users can access the user list/see user profiles. How can I change this without getting an error?

currently, when I remove the :index portion on line 3, I get the following error.

undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass

This is in line 4 of /app/views/users/_user.html.erb

```
<li>
2:   <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
3:   <%= link_to user.name, user %>
4:   <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
5:     | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?" %>
6:   <% end %>
7: </li>
```

Comment: Just removing the :index of the array is not enough ?
If not, please provide us more information : error, unexpected behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your have something like `root :to => 'users#index'` in your `routes.rb` file.

Common solutions for 'signed in / not signed in' behavior involves conditionally redirecting based on authentication states, or rendering various partials depending on state.

Under `index`, your `@users` instance variable will always contain paginated User models, regardless of state. However, we have no way of knowing what `signed_in_user` does. If you search for `def signed_in_user` in your code, you can see what it does. That may reveal something about how the app handles the state of authentication--or also how to proceed if that is what you are building out.

**Update**

So it looks like you are not populating the `current_user` object. This is typically a method that will return an object.

If you are using Devise, you may have to do some additional configuration for it in order to make that `current_user` helper method available to your view.

The `nil` error is resulting from the fact that `current_user` returns nil, or simply doesn't exist. So it's essentially trying `nil.admin?` and causing the Error to be raised.

Maybe the logic you are looking for is,

```
<li>
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
| <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?" %>
<% end %>
```

You can also investigate the value of `current_user` from the Rails debugger console. You can add a `debugger` statement in your controller, and then play around. Also, you can use the Rails console (run `rails console` from the command line) and play around there too.

**Update 2**

> so why is it that there are no problems populating the current_user
>   object when I include :index. Why would removing that (see question
>   above) cause current_user to become depopulated

We can't know what is in the `signed_in_user` method to investigate further.

However, I have a hunch that `current_user == nil` is `true` because you haven't logged in at all.

Comment: so why is it that there are no problems populating the current_user object when I include :index. Why would removing that (see question above) cause current_user to become depopulated